# Get table names from POSTGIS database with PyQGIS

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, qgis, database-table

How can I access the table names inside a POSTGIS database with PyQGIS?
I am trying to load a layer from A POSTGIS database. I can do it if I know the table's name which I am gonna use.

Comment: You might have better luck on http://gis.stackexchange.com/ for questions on how to use GIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want list of tables name from current database.

```
from PyQt4.QtSql import *
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("postgres");
    db.setUserName("postgres");
    db.setPassword("postgres");
    db.open();
    names=db.tables( QSql.Tables)
    print names
```